# How to change code of a live page without bringing down the service?

Tags: web-services, web, web-deployment

After more than sufficient googling and hitting dead-ends, i want to ask community if some one can point me to correct direction

**My Question is :**

I have some new features which i need to implement on one of my existing site.Due to some constraint i can not stop the web-service, so how can i implement the changes that i have done on my page from localhost to live-server?

Site is coded in PHP (*if this info helps*!! :) )

Its similar to what Google, LinkedIn and facebook does on their social network - implementing new chats windows or making a jquery box `pop-up` for a *tour* on page refresh (*experienced this many times*)

Any help / pointers is appreciated.

thanks!

***PS :*** feel free to re-tag the question! :)

Comment: Huge companies like Google and Facebook will undoubtedly use a failover/switching/cluster mechanism where they have instances of the site being updated and once they've competed testing they switch to this version... OR, much smaller, do your maintenance at known quiet times. Plan your maintenance, make your DB read only, upload your updates and then re-open your DB. SO does this. Visitors are made aware of it and the updates are completed very quickly. Minimal disruption.

Comment: *they switch to this version* - thats what i want to know....i have an alternate server for backend, but when i would *switch* even that would disrupt service for some time atleast....wont it!?

Comment: You could look up a load balancer mechanism and take down your primary node to do the update, once the updates are working and you're happy bring it back online and take down the second node to make sure it's updated to the same code as node1. The balancer will take care of the no disruption...